# How to get data from a specific section in MediaWiki supported wikis

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

[image]

I am parsing a Wikia article and trying to get the data from the right hand side highlighted block, I have already got the left one using the following URL

```
http://hetalia.wikia.com/api.php?action=parse&prop=revisions&prop=sections&page=America&format=json
```

But don't know the reference about the right one. What will be the parameter?

The original URL is,

```
http://hetalia.wikia.com/wiki/America
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to get info from the Infoboxes would be to get the page source, which can be done with this query

```
http://hetalia.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=America&format=json
```

And then parsing the text to get the information, as the source of that box is in this format

```
{{Character
|name = America
|jname = アメリカ
|image = America0.png
|country = [[wikipedia:United States|The United States of America]]
|human = Alfred F.Jones (アルフレッド・F・ジョーンズ, ''Arufureddo F. Joonzu'')
|age = 19
...
|japanese = [[Katsuyuki Konishi]], Ryoko Shimizu (Young America, drama CD "Prologue"), [[Ai Iwamura]] (Young America, anime), [[Axis Powers Hetalia: The CD|Osamu Ikeda]] (''Flower Of Iris'')
|english = [[Eric Vale]], Stephanie Young (young America)}}
```

You could use Regex to extract the data from the text, such as using `\|age\s*=\s*(\d*)` to get the age attribute.